# vb.net Sending email message to recipients one at a time, no bcc

Tags: vb.net, email

I am working on a mailing system, sending the same email one by one, but I do not want to use bcc because the information sent has different information queried from the database. I query the database and add all the email addresses into an array, then with the array I call a function to send the email sending the address and the html page reference as parameters. My problem is that the message repeats itself as many times as their are email recipients. For example for 3 recipients each one gets the message three times. I keep using msg.to.clear() to clear the recipients but the program still calls the function three times.

> Protected Sub btnSend_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles
>   btnSend.Click
>       SendHTMLMail() End Sub
>
> Public Sub SendHTMLMail()
>
> ```
> Dim toaddress As String = ""
> Dim red As String = (Server.MapPath("~/HTMLPage.htm"))
>
> Dim ta As New DataSet1TableAdapters.pruebasTableAdapter
> Dim dt As DataSet1.pruebasDataTable
> Dim r As DataSet1.pruebasRow
> Dim x As Integer = ta.conteo()
> Dim s(x - 1) As String
> Dim y = x
> Dim z = 0
> dt = ta.GetDataBy1()
> Dim mystring = ""
>
> For Each r In dt
>     s(z) = r.email
>     z = z + 1
> Next
>
> For i As Integer = 0 To (y - 1)
>     sendEmailtoaddress(s(i), red)
>     MsgBox("sent" + s(i).ToString)
>     mystring += s(i).ToString + ", "
> Next
>
> Label1.Text = mystring
> 'Label1.Text = "Enviando mensaje!"
>
>
> 'Label1.Text += "Mensaje enviado exitosamente!"
> ```
>
> End Sub
>
> Shared Function sendEmailtoaddress(ByVal toaddress As String, ByVal
>   serverpath As String) As Integer
>
> ```
> Dim x As Integer
> Dim reader As New StreamReader(serverpath)
> Dim readFile As String = reader.ReadToEnd()
> Dim myString As String = ""
> myString = readFile
> Dim Msg As New MailMessage()
> 'Dim fromMail As New MailAddress("info@gc.hn")
> Dim fromMail As New MailAddress("ramonhasbun@gmail.com")
> ' Sender e-mail address.
> Msg.From = fromMail
> ' Recipient e-mail address.
> Dim emailad As New MailAddress(toaddress)
> Msg.To.Clear()
> Msg.To.Add(emailad)
>
> ' Subject of e-mail
> Msg.Subject = "Bufete González Corrales"
> Msg.Body = myString.ToString()
> Msg.IsBodyHtml = True
> Dim sSmtpServer As String = ""
> 'sSmtpServer = "smtp.live.com"
> sSmtpServer = "smtp.gmail.com"
> Dim a As New SmtpClient()
> a.Host = sSmtpServer
> a.Port = 587
> ' a.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential("info@gc.hn", "PASSWORD")
> a.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential("ramonhasbun@gmail.com", "PASSWORD")
> a.EnableSsl = True
> a.Send(Msg)
> reader.Dispose()
>
> Return x
> ```

I added the a.dispose() function at the end of the mail sending function and now I get only two copies of the message. I think that the For i As Integer = 0 To (y - 1)... is being called twice.

The program sends the first 3 emails and then resends them.

Comment: `each one gets the message three times` That sounds wrong.  Please specify _exactly_ what happens.

Comment: After I added the msg.dispose() the messages sent twice, first the program sends the  emails and then sends them again. When I debug step by step the for i that reads the array runs twice.  Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

```
mystring += s(i).ToString + ", "
```

You just appended the next message inside the loop, without clearing the old one.

Comment: Yes, I do append but that part is used only to see how many times it gets called and the mystring variable is not used to send email thanks for your support

Comment: Problem solved, rewrote the code into a new Project in visual studio, using arrays to store and call the email addresses one by one.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, rewrote the code into a new Project in visual studio, using arrays to store and call the email addresses one by one.

Fill the array...

```
         For Each r In dt
            emails(j) = r.email
            j = j + 1
         Next
```

Read the array and send emails one by one...

```
 For i As Integer = 0 To (x - 1)
        Mail.Subject = "Subject"
        Mail.To.Clear()
        Mail.To.Add(emails(i).ToString)
        Mail.From = New MailAddress("EMAIL ADDRESS")
        Mail.Body = myString.ToString()
        Mail.IsBodyHtml = True

        Dim SMTP As New SmtpClient("SMTP SERVER")
        SMTP.EnableSsl = True
        SMTP.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential(TextBox1.Text,TextBox2.Text)
        SMTP.Port = "PORT NUMBER"
        SMTP.Send(Mail)
        MsgBox("Message sent to: " + emails(i).ToString())
    Next
```